# Virtualize a disk partition for dual boot?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I've been a long time Windows user but I've found that it's pretty easy to corrupt the registry and have it clobber your EFI system partition. Naturally I'd want to protect on that in a dual-boot system without virtualizing Windows inside of Linux. I've come up with a scheme as follows:

My drive is split into a couple of partitions:

ESP

Linux swap partition

Shared NTFS partition between Windows and Linux + growth buffer

Recovery Linux partition

Linux root filesystem + growth buffer

Windows root filesystem + growth buffer (and friends)

​

What I want to do is put rEFInd on the ESP and have it chainload to either Linux or Windows. I don't exactly trust Windows so I am wanting to restrict its access rights to the ESP, possibly by having a second faked out one, or something else. I've thought of a few ideas:

Is it possible to expose only the Windows partitions as a set of virtual disks to it, with kernel panics following on illegal accesses to the other partitions?

Is it possible to mount the Linux partitions as read-only or otherwise mark them as private / hidden to Windows, but allow Linux access to the whole drive when it's booted? I.e. can we set some attributes for the Linux partitions and then unset them when we actually boot Linux?

I've seen it's possible to use Linux as a chainloader for Windows, which might be the best way of achieving what I want, but this is very new territory, if not research.

​

Obviously I could plant Windows on a separate hard drive but at that point it's not really all that different from installing windows to a specific region of my existing hard drive (minus all of the sector offsets). How can I best virtualize precise regions of a hard disk to Windows, with access rights and scope removed everywhere else?

Comment: Windows is not that unstable and corruptions are very rare, unless you do unsafe operations or get it infected with a virus. I think your fears are unfounded, but you can always install Windows as a virtual machine under Linux in total isolation (not the best solution).

Comment: I would say I've had a miserable time with sporadic reboots on my all AMD system on Windows 11 and I've spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out which piece of hardware could be culprit. So far I've come up short and have not experienced any instabilities on Linux. I will definitely agree that Windows really doesn't know how to handle unstable operations. I feel like I get myself into such situations while tinkering, so I think there's a perfect storm of factors that often require a clean install on Windows for me. To some extent I'm basically trying to idiot proof against myself.

Comment: It has been repeated *ad nauseum* that when dual-booting with Windows its Fast Startup feature must be disabled. Very likely this is the root cause of whatever problems you had.

Comment: Sadly, had that disabled as I have never trusted fastboot on Windows. seemed to misbehave quite spectacularly regardless